# Filerenaming loop not functioning

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-rename

I'm having trouble understanding why my code doesn't work.
I want to rename each file in a particular folder in an order like this:
Foldername_1
Foldername_2 
Foldername_3 
etc...

The code I wrote should increase the 'num' variable by 1 every time it reloops the for loop.

```
path = os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(path)

    for filename in filenames:
        num = 0
        num = num + 1
        name = "Foldername_{}".format(num)
        os.rename(filename, "{}".format(name))
```

However I'm getting this Error:

> FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file
>   already exists: '90' -> 'Foldername_1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `num` to 0 *for each iteration*. Move the `num = 0` *out* of the loop:

```
num = 0
for filename in filenames:
    num = num + 1
    name = "Foldername_{}".format(num)
    os.rename(filename, "{}".format(name))
```

You don't need to format the `name` variable again; `"{}".format(name)` produces the same string as what is already in `name`. And rather than manually increment a number, you could use the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to produce the number for you:

```
for num, filename in enumerate(filenames, 1):
    name = "Foldername_{}".format(num)
    os.rename(filename, name)
```

Take into account that `os.listdir()` doesn't list names in alphabetical order; rather, you'll get an order that is based on the on-disk directory structure, which depends on the order files where created and the exact filesystem implementation. You may want to sort manually:

```
for num, filename in enumerate(sorted(filenames), 1):
```